# How to substitute values in file between 2 strings

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to replace the value between http:// and :80 dynamically everytime with a IP address that I am fetching. I have written below script to get the value and replace the placeholder 'localhost' with the IP address. But I want it to replace value betwen http:// and :80 and not by matching with localhost as it may change.

Line to substitute value in:

```
"UIApiPath": "http://localhost:80/uisvc/v1/api",
"serviceApiPath": "http://localhost:80/servicesvc/v1/api",
"DBApiPath": "http://locahost:80/DBsvc/v1/api"
```

Existing script for fetching and replacing value by matching 'localhost':

```
#!/bin/bash
DEPLOYMENT_NAME=$1
# Getting the pod name from the deployment object
GETTING_POD_NAME=$(kubectl describe deploy $1 | grep 'NewReplicaSet:' | awk '{print $2}')
# Getting the ip-address from pod description
echo ''
GETTING_IP_ADDRESS=$(kubectl describe pod $GETTING_POD_NAME | sed -n '4p' | awk '{print $2}')
# Getting the correct ip-address
SERVER_IP=${GETTING_IP_ADDRESS#*/}
echo $SERVER_IP
# Path of book-store-app configmap file:
APP_CONFIGMAP_FILE_PATH=deployment/java-apps/app-configmap.yaml
# Configure the ip-address in the configmap
sed -i "s/localhost/$SERVER_IP/g" $APP_CONFIGMAP_FILE_PATH
```

Comment: Did you tried something? Have a look at `info sed`!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Simple `sed` command based on `//` string:

```
sed "s#//[^:/]\+:80/#//$SERVER_IP:80/#" -i $APP_CONFIGMAP_FILE_PATH
```

Could do the job! (While `$SERVER_IP` variable don't hold any `#` character.)

#### Explanation

Note: Cited paragraph are copied from `info sed` pages.

- `s` is normal replacment command under `sed`

  > ```
  > The syntax of the 's' command is 's/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/FLAGS'.
  > ...
  > ```
- `#` is used as *command separator*;

  > ```
  > The '/' characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single
  > character within any given 's' command...
  > ```
- `[^:/]` mean any character, but no *slashes* `/` and no *colons* `:`.

  > ```
  > A "bracket expression" is a list of characters enclosed by '[' and ']'.
  > It matches any single character in that list; if the first character of
  > the list is the caret '^', then it matches any character *not* in the
  > list.
  > ```
- `*` mean any number (even zero) of previous character (no slashes nor colons)

  > ```
  > '*'
  >     Matches a sequence of zero or more instances of matches for the
  >     preceding regular expression, which must be an ordinary character,
  >     a special character preceded by '\', a '.', a grouped regexp (see
  >     below), or a bracket expression. 
  > ...
  > '\+'
  >     As '*', but matches one or more.
  > ```

I insist: Please read carefully `info sed`!

Comment: Thanks a lot!..This is working. But one observation I made, when there is no data between http:// and :80 for eg: http:// :80 , this doesnot enter the IP address between them. Only when there is a character it will substitute with the IP..Can you help with this?

Comment: You could replace *escaped plus* sign by an *asterisk* (without escape): `[^:/]\+` by `[^:/]*` for this. Then please consider *accept answer* and/or *upvote answer*  if this answer match your need!

Comment: Thanks! This helps. Can you please explain the command, I am a beginner with sed and would like to understand how the substitution is happening here.